# Electron "Error occurred in handler for" ipcRenderer.invoke

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm getting this error when invoking a channel in electron. I want to be able to send a http axios request via Main Process (prevent Cors Issues):

```
Error invoking remote method 'an-action': No handler registered for 'an-action'
    at EventEmitter.i.invoke (electron/js2c/renderer_init.js:73)
```

The setup is pretty straightforward. I can't find any great documentation for examples. Apart from:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer

my main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const axios = require("axios");

//*** Creating app goes here ***//

function createWindow() {
   ...
   ipcMain.handle('an-action', async (event, axios_request) => {
        const result = await axios(axios_request)
        return { data: result.data, status: result.status }
   });
   ...
}
```

my examplePage.js

```
import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron';

// Some Vue3 stuff

onButtonPress: function() {
   ipcRenderer.invoke('an-action',
         {
           data: {
           },
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'http://example.com/',
         },
        ).then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
        });
}
```

Not too sure how to troubleshoot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure your `handle` method is being called?

Comment: ... I'm being stupid - just realised this application does not use main.js, but uses background.js (which both contained the same code!) So changing main.js wasn't actually doing anything!!!!!! Thanks Pushkin for making be spot being silly.